# Setting <div> height to 100% works on desktop but not tablet?

Tags: css, html

UPDATE:
(i) the fact I was using px for widths had nothing to do with it (yes it's a terrible habit, but it wasn't causing the problem)
(ii) it seems something about the diagonal buttons on the right was causing it, I suspect because of what I was having to do with their positioning to make them look 'right', so am now working on a different way of getting that button effect
(iii) I would LOVE to know why I lost rep for this . . .

ORIGINAL POST:
am going nuts! I'm making a website for a friend. You can view it here: jameslago.co.uk

As you can see, he wants a series of stripes down either side. I am using multiple `<div>`s, lots of floating and positioning stuff, including setting height: 100%. This is working fine on desktop (have checked in the major browsers - chrome, firefox, IE9, safari, opera). I mean, my CSS looks clunky, but it all works. However, on a tablet, I get loads of white space at the bottom, even worse when I turn it to portrait. This problem doesn't show up in the emulator (am using ripple), just when I actually view the site on my tablet. My friend has had the same problem on his tablet (I have a nexus, he has an ipad).

I have the same problem when viewing it on my phone - on there, it actually cuts it off in landscape orientation.

It's almost as though it is setting the height to the screen width (the shorter edge of the device). But why is it doing this on mobile devices but not on desktop? And why, if it is doing that, am I getting white space when in landscape (as you'd think that would work?) And how do I make it fit 100% of the height on a tablet/phone?

Here is my rather monstrous CSS:

```
/* reset browser styles */
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1.2;
}
ol { 
    padding-left: 1.4em;
    list-style: decimal;
}
ul {
    padding-left: 1.4em;
    list-style: square;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
} 
/* end reset browser styles */

body, html {
    margin: 0;   
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1360px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: hidden;   
}

.wrap {
    margin: auto;
    background-color:#565656;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}


.leftMenu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;    
    width: 160px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #212121;     
}

.greyLeft {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 160px;    
    width:40px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#565656;   
}

.blackLeft {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;  
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#212121;   
}

.orangeLeft {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 220px;    
    width: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FA8700;       
}

.thinLeft {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 260px;    
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#212121;  
}

.thinRight {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 260px;   
    width:20px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#212121;
}


.orangeRight {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 220px;  
    width: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FA8700;    
}

.blackRight {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 200px;   
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#212121;
}


.greyRight {
    margin:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 160px; 
    width:40px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#565656;
}



.rightMenu {    
    margin: auto;
    float: right;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px; 
    width: 160px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #212121;        
}



.diag {    
     position: absolute;    
     overflow: hidden;  
}

.logo {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 20px;
    float: right;
}

.central {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 800px;
    overflow: scroll;
    left: 280px;
    right: 240px;   
    margin: auto;    
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: impact, Arial;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color:#212121;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.central h1 {
    text-align: center;    
}

.galleryContainer {
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    right: 250px;
    bottom: -30px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;    
    text-align: center;
    font-family: impact;
    color:#212121;
    font-size: 16pt;    
}

.slideshow {    
   width: 750px;
   height: 500px;
   margin: 50px auto;
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: #565656;
   border: 2px #565656 solid;
}

.small {   
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;   
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px #565656 solid;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
}



.big { 
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.innerBig {
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}

.makeMiddle {
    width: 705px;
    margin: auto;    
}

.description {
   text-align: center;
    font-family: impact;
    color:#212121;
    font-size: 12pt;

}

a:link {border: none; text-decoration:none;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {border: none; text-decoration:none;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {border: none; text-decoration:none;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {border: none; text-decoration:none;}  /* selected link */
```

I've done another site using one left-hand div, setting height to 100%, and that's behaving itself perfectly. I can't see what I've done differently, apart from there being a lot more `<div>`s in this one!

Answer (score 0):

For full responsiveness of the website 
1) either you have to define two css. i.e one for dextop view and one for Mobile or tablet view.

2) All the dimensions try to be in **%** value you have defined some values in **%** but maximum dimensions are in **px** so  please try to avoid those things.

It will work.

Comment: Hiya, thank you for replying. I know setting widths in px and heights in % is messy, but it shouldn't be causing this problem should it?

Comment: And why wouldn't 'height: 100%' work on both desktop and tablet? I'm not trying to make the layout any different on either device.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .galleryContainer {
        z-index: 0;
        overflow: scroll;
        position: absolute;
        left: 250px;
        right: 250px; 
        bottom: -30px;
        margin: auto;
        height: 100%;    
        text-align: center;
        font-family: impact;
        color:#212121;
        font-size: 16pt;    
    }
```

> Like this code you have already used
>
> ```
>     position: absolute;
>     left: 250px;
>     right: 250px; 
>     bottom: -30px;
> ```
>
> try to avoid px use % it will work.